# Read csv data in Pandas like in the tutorial

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to follow along the Pandas tutorial, reading and writing data. (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/intro_tutorials/02_read_write.html)
I've got to this command

```
titanic = pd.read_csv("data/titanic.csv")
```

which gives me this error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data/titanic.csv'
```

I know I can go and download that file from somewhere, and put it in a data folder in my working directory, and this will work, but should it just work without me doing that? The tutorial doesn't mention downloading the data, and the Pandas GitHub repo appears to have the data folder in it. Does this mean `titanic.csv` is a built in data set, and if so, how do I access it?

Comment: yep the error is exactly what it says - the file does not exist on your file system.  plus checked my system it doesn't exist anywhere

Comment: ok, thanks! I'm used to R with built in data sets, so I kinda expected it, especially as the tutorial didn't seem to say anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, the tutorial doesn't mention downloading the data, however that's the only way to do it. The command below only works if you have the file saved on your computer:

```
pd.read_csv("anyfile.csv")
```

csv files are not 'built in' with pandas.

You can download the data by clicking the 'Titanic data' -> 'to raw data' - button in the link you provided.